# transforming the dataset with conditions

Tags: python, pandas

The values are correspondent to the kind of Plan that a customer have:

df (only a row)

```
Customer|mar_x|abr|may|jun|jul|aug |sep|oct|nov|dez|jan|feb|mar_y                 
x        |NaN  |NaN|NaN|NaN|7.5|30.0|7.5|7.5|7.5|7.5|7.5|7.5|7.5
```

I want to transform the values into a Status depending on how was the status in a month ago.

if there was no value, this is going to be a 'new'
if the value is equal to before is going to be 'existing'
if the value is bigger than before, 'upgraded'
if the value is smaller than before, 'downgraded'

Desires Output:

```
Mar_x|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec|Jan|Feb|Mar_y
-    |-  |-  |-  | N | U | D | E |E  |  E|E  |E  |E
```

Comment: Is the data for the customer from the previous month stored in a different row in that dataframe? If so, can we assume the dataframe is sorted by date (and if not can you add the date to the dataframe so that you can sort by date)?

Comment: it's not stored. this was an interval from start_date to end_date that i just turned into that data set separed by months with the values

Comment: Ah right. I see what you are after. Just a moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you are looking for:

```
# read in your data
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([
    [np.nan,7.5,30.0,np.nan,7.5,30.0,7.5,np.nan,np.nan,7.5,7.5,np.nan,np.nan]],
    columns=['Mar_x','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec','Jan','Feb','Mar_y'])

# function to return the new, upgrade, downgrade, etc
def value_comparison(diff):
    if diff==0:
        return 'E'
    elif diff > 0:
        return 'U'
    elif diff < 0:
        return 'D'
    else:
        return 'N'

# get the forward difference in time
df_diff = df.ffill(axis=1).diff(axis=1)
# apply the map to return your states
df_results = df_diff.apply(lambda row: row.apply(value_comparison), axis=1)
# correct for the NaN states where the forward difference was not defined
df_results[df.isna()]= np.nan
# correct for the case when the user cancels
mask = (df.isna() & ~df.shift(1, axis=1).isna())
df_results[mask] = 'C'
# correct for renew
mask = (~df.isna() & df.shift(1, axis=1).isna())
df_results[mask[mask == True].cumsum(axis=1) > 1] = 'Renew'
# result
print(df_results)
```

Result:

```
  Mar_x Apr May Jun    Jul Aug Sep Oct  Nov    Dec Jan Feb Mar_y
0   NaN   N   U   C  Renew   U   D   C  NaN  Renew   E   C   NaN
```

Comment: I was trying to make a similar approach:
def status(row):
    if (row[-1]>row[-2]) & (row[-2] is not None):
        return 'Upgraded'
    elif (row[-2] is None) & (row[-1] is not None):
        return 'New'
    elif (row[-1] is None) & (row[-2] is not None):
        return 'Churned'
    elif (row[-1]==row[-2]) & (row[-1] is not None):
        return 'Existing'

df_test = df4.apply(status, axis=1)

but it'd just create one column, so i'd have to iterate through another columns and create a new DF based on that

Comment: Also, using your method i'd had to compare the value to the previous column. Do you know how could we do that?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little? What do you mean by "i'd had to compare the value to the previous column"? The `df.diff(axis=1)` method above does that comparison.

Comment: for this is instance it's not getting the New values
https://i.imgur.com/cX0Jm2t.png

Comment: Also, i'm DUMB and forgot to mention that if there is a month in 'E' and the next with nothing. this has to be a 'Canceled' 'C'

Comment: See the updates. Sorry, I realised that the np.nan wasn't catching the 'N' cases correctly. The `else` term should now have that right. Then for the 'C' use case, we ffill the dataframe and compare the NaNs in the original df to the NaNs in the difference df

Comment: This is almost Perfect! thank you so much! Just one last question: is it possible to keep the 'C' value ONLY in the period/month of canceling, so the next month would be 'NaN'

Comment: Sure. Yup. You just need the `cumsum` in the mask term that indexes the items that are cancels. See updates.

Comment: hey, everything went right but between many cases i found only one exception ): which is basically a new status. A reactivaded status, when a customer cancel and after that he comes back again. a customer X is     6.25 6.25 6.25 6.25 6.25 NaN 6.25 6.25 6.25  through the periods. so i means after he canceled, the next month is a reactivantion and after the reactivation, it'll be existing again

Comment: So is it the 'C's, 'N's or 'E's that are issues. For the 'C's if you change the `cancel_month = (~df_diff.isna() & df.isna()).cumsum(axis=1) == 1` line to not include the parenthesis then you'll get more than one cancel event.

Comment: i'm trying to make a reactivated based on: reactivate = (~df_diff.isna() & df.shift(1,axis=1).isna() & ~df.shift(2,axis=1).isna() & ~df.isna())

and a new Canaceled: churn_df = (df == 0) & (diff_df < 0)
churn_df.applymap(lambda x: 'C' if x == True else '').head()

Comment: the problem with my canceled formula is that in the month 12 its always gonna be 'C' due to the next position....

Comment: Your solution using shift is a good one. There should be ways to tweak what you want out of a mask: `mask = (~df.isna() & df.shift(1, axis=1).isna()) # all items that have an item to the left being NaN` and then
`mask[mask == True].cumsum(axis=1)`

Comment: So the values in the above that are 1 correspond to N. The values that are greater than 1 correspond to reactivated... I suppose you can do something analogous for the cancels.

Comment: make sense to reactivated. didn't understand how it'd work for the cancels.

Comment: I have edited one last time. I am sure you can play around with the mask variable to tweak to the result that you want. All the best :).